# Can PDF XML metadata be attached to individual elements of the PDF or just the entire file?

Tags: pdf, xmp

We are looking to embed metadata attached to elements as well as individual page objects in PDF but are not clear on whether XMP would be the right solution.  As an alternative we have considered embeddeding code in the annotations attached to each object in the pdf.

Any ideas on how to embed metadata to individual pdf elements?

Answer (score 2):

PDF Reference states that:

> In general, a PDF stream or dictionary can have metadata attached to
>   it as long as the stream or dictionary represents an actual
>   information resource, as opposed to serving as an implementation
>   artifact. Some PDF constructs are considered implementational, and
>   hence cannot have associated metadata.

So you might add XMP metadata to almost any stream or dictionary in a PDF file. And to PDF file as whole, of course (i.e to document catalog dictionary).

You will probably need to use a PDF library that is capable to add XMP metadata to document and individual objects within it. Or a library that gives you low level access to PDF objects.